# How to debug the C# error c5266?

Tags: c#

Error:

> CS0266    Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte' to 'sbyte'. An explicit conversion exists

Code:

```
public sbyte ReadSByte()
        {
            byte[] arg_17_0 = this._buffer;
            int position = this._position;
            this._position = position + 1;
            return arg_17_0[position];
        }
```

Comment: You are returning a `byte` when the function ask for an `sbyte`.

Comment: @CodingYoshi OP is not trying to return a byte array.

Answer (score 1):

Since your method signature is indicating it will return  `sbyte`, and the callers of the method will expect that, you should return a `sbyte`. Therefore, you need to cast from a `byte` to an `sbyte` and then return that. Like this:

```
return unchecked((sbyte)arg_17_0[position]);
```

Here is some info about the `checked` keyword in case you are interested (but above will work without it too):

> Because checking for overflow takes time, the use of unchecked code in situations where there is no danger of overflow might improve performance. However, if overflow is a possibility, a checked environment should be used.

Comment: Actually the C# compiler uses unchecked for math by default.

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting a sbyte return from the statement below.

```
public sbyte ReadSByte()
```

but you returned a byte value.

```
byte[] arg_17_0 = this._buffer;  
return arg_17_0[position];
```